# adding jquery datepicker in MVC 5 project?

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I could add successfully the jquery Date-picker to my project which is in MVC5.
Works perfectly in development machine but when moved to production server or installed on any other machine then css file of Jquery Date-pciker doesn't get loaded.

files (CSS + images) are uploaded for Jquery UI

i can see css files in C:/inetpub/wwwroot/website1/Content/themes/base
and images of Jquery UI in C:/inetpub/wwwroot/website1/Content/themes/base/images.

But in my Bundle.Config i am specifying css

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/core.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/theme.css"));
```

Do i need to specify for images also or will the css file of Jquery will automatically pick from the images folder of Jquery UI?

I checked the output in html for the css it appear like **href="/Website/Content/themes/base?v=2Vq5_iMpJLFNII_xHdCkMM__OAdzgi5itwFpkyF2q2s1‌​"**

Where as in development machine it looks **href="/Content/themes/base/core.css"** & **href="/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css"** & **href="/Content/themes/base/theme.css"**. All the css are loaded correctly.

if we expand it says "Reload the page to get source for: **localhost/Website/Content/themes/base?v=2Vq5_iMpJLFNII_xHdCkMM__OAdzgi5itwFpkyF2q2s1**

Thanks.

Comment: Path being wrong; files not uploaded; etc...

Comment: If path is wrong then how it is working on Development machine? And files are uploaded because i can see css files in C:/inetpub/wwwroot/website1/Content/themes/base

Comment: And images of Jquery UI inside C:/inetpub/wwwroot/website1/Content/themes/base/images

Comment: Double check your links. Almost guarantee that is your problem. Look at your relative urls. But really, without seeing the code, all we can do is guess

Comment: I have just added the BundleConfig.cs code now.

Comment: Ok... check what is actually output in the html, and if the files ate really there

Comment: I checked the output in html for the css it appear like href="/Website/Content/themes/base?v=2Vq5_iMpJLFNII_xHdCkMM__OAdzgi5itwFpkyF2q2s1"

Comment: Does that URL load in the browser? And is all of your code deployed? That's trying to load the bundle URL, of course.

Comment: Where as in development machine it looks href="/Content/themes/base/core.css" & href="/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css" & href="/Content/themes/base/theme.css". All the css are loaded correctly.

Comment: That is trying to load entire bundle URL and not one each file. How test whether the bundle is being loaded or not? Also if we expand it says "Reload the page to get source for: http://localhost/Website/Content/themes/base?v=2Vq5_iMpJLFNII_xHdCkMM__OAdzgi5itwFpkyF2q2s1"

Comment: Hmmm... okay; I'm not as familiar with the bundling, so I can't help there. You should edit in some of the extra data that's here in the comments. I've reopened in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks for opening the question though.